# Flatten 3-d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to flatten this:

```
b = np.array([
    [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
    [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
])
```

into:

```
c = np.array([
    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
])
```

Niether of these work:

```
c = np.apply_along_axis(np.ndarray.flatten, 0, b)
c = np.apply_along_axis(np.ndarray.flatten, 0, b)
```

Just returns the same array.

It would be great to flatten this in place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
c=b.reshape(len(b),-1)
```

Then `c` is

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: What  `-1` does in `reshape` ?

Comment: It's a shortcut to automatically calculate the size of that dimension.  Since `b.size = 18` and `len(b) = 2`, the `-1` is calculated to be `18 / 2 = 9`

Answer (score 2):

You can completely flatten and then reshape:

```
c = b.flatten().reshape(b.shape[0],b.shape[1]*b.shape[2])
```

Output

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could always just use reshape:

```
b.reshape((2,9)) 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]])
```